# Getting extremely large arrows with tikzcd

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have a quite large description of an arrow, and `row sep = huge` does not make the arrow long enough. Is there a way to format this better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = huge, row sep = huge]
E \arrow[r, "e"] & \Pi_{i \in ob(\mathcal{E})} F(i) \arrow[r, shift left, " 
{<\pi_{cod(u)} \ | \ u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})>}"] \arrow[r, shift right, "{<F(u) 
\pi_{dom(u)} \ | \ u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})}"'] & {\Pi_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E}) 
F(cod(u))}} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've never seen `huge` as an argument for `column sep` before. If you look in the tikz-cd manual, you'll notice that you can give any arbitrary length (say 5cm) instead of `huge`, then manual states what `huge` is an alias for.

Comment: That said I'd probably consider rewriting this diagram instead and it will not be particularly readable for the reader anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two different ways

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\cod}{cod}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ob}{ob}

\begin{document}

Option 1: wide column separation specified by dimension
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzcd}[column sep = 10em]
    E \arrow[r, "e"] & \displaystyle\prod_{i \in
    \ob(\mathcal{E})} \mkern-12mu F(i)
    \arrow[r, shift left, " {\langle\pi_{\cod(u)} \mid u \in
    \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"] \arrow[r, shift right, "{\langle F(u)
    \pi_{\dom(u)} \mid u \in
    \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"']
    & {\displaystyle\prod_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})} \mkern-12mu F(\cod(u))}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

Option 2: let arrows cover two (or more) columns
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{tikzcd}[column sep = huge]
    E \arrow[r, "e"]
    & \displaystyle\prod_{i \in \ob(\mathcal{E})} \mkern-12mu F(i)
    \arrow[rr, shift left, " {\langle\pi_{\cod(u)} \mid u \in
    \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"]
    \arrow[rr, shift right, "{\langle F(u) \pi_{\dom(u)}
    \mid u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"']
    && {\displaystyle\prod_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})} \mkern-12mu F(\cod(u))}
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The first is simply to specify the `column sep` as a dimension.
The second is to add an extra column under the long arrows, so you have

```
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[rr] && C
```

instead of

```
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r] & C
```

You can make this wider by using more columns

```
A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[rrr] &&& C
```

etc.

Note I have recoded much of your mathematics.

The above solutions corresponding to working with a fixed grid, which is often a good idea for consistent spacing.  An alternative is the extra space syntax of egreg's answer:

```
&[5em]
```

in the first row, will push the subsequent column `5em` to the right and so making the corresponding arrows longer.

Answer (score 7):

Add a width specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ob}{ob}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cod}{cod}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
E \arrow[r, "e"] &
  \prod_{i \in \ob(\mathcal{E})} F(i)
  \arrow[
    r, shift left,
    "{\langle\pi_{\cod(u)} \mid u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"
  ]
  \arrow[
    r, shift right,
    "{\langle F(u)\pi_{\dom(u)} \mid u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"'
  ] &[8em]
  \prod_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})} F(\cod(u))
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Note the adjustments I made:

- `<...>` should be `\langle...\rangle`
- `\Pi` should be `\prod`
- `\ | \` should be `\mid`
- ob, dom and cod should be typeset upright

[image]

A possible alternative with `\smashoperator` that makes the diagram shorter:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ob}{ob}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cod}{cod}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
E \arrow[r, "e"] &
  \smashoperator{\prod_{i \in \ob(\mathcal{E})}} F(i)
  \arrow[
    r, shift left,
    "{\langle\pi_{\cod(u)} \mid u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"
  ]
  \arrow[
    r, shift right,
    "{\langle F(u)\pi_{\dom(u)} \mid u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"'
  ] &[10em]
  \smashoperator{\prod_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})}} F(\cod(u))
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Eventually, someone who knows the `&[<lenght>]` option, you beat me by a second, lol!

Comment: +1 Of course, loading `amsmath` is not needed once you load `mathtools`.

Answer (score 4):

Add an empty column between columns 2 and 3. I also added some improvements to the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep= huge, row sep=huge]
E \arrow[r, "e"] & \Pi_{i \in ob(\mathcal{E})} F(i) \arrow[rr, shift left=1ex, "
{\langle\pi_{cod(u)} \, | \, u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"] \arrow[rr, shift right=1ex, "{\langle F(u)
\pi_{dom(u)} \, | \, u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle}"'] & & {\Pi_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})
F(cod(u))}}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I remade everything in normal Ti*k*Z and correct (many) typos. Also, take note that I use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`. A curve is always more readable than a straight line in this case in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ob}{ob}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cod}{cod}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\node (mid) {$\prod_{i \in \ob(\mathcal{E})} F(i)$};
\node[left=1cm of mid] (left) {$E$};
\node[right=4cm of mid] (right) {$\prod_{u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})}F(\cod(u))$};
\draw[->] (left)--(mid) node[midway,above] {$\scriptstyle e$};
\draw[->] ([yshift=.2em]mid.east) to[bend left=5] node[midway,above] {$\scriptstyle\langle\pi_{\cod(u)} \ | \ u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle$} ([yshift=.2em]right.west);
\draw[->] ([yshift=-.2em]mid.east) to[bend right=5] node[midway,below] {$\scriptstyle\langle F(u)\pi_{\dom(u)} \ | \ u \in \hom(\mathcal{E})\rangle$} ([yshift=-.2em]right.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]